# Estimate a numerical value through Spark MLlib Regression

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, regression, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm training a Spark MLlib linear regressor but I believe I didn't understand part of the libraries hands-on usage.

I have 1 feature (`NameItem`) and one output (`Accumulator`).
The first one is categorical (Speed, Temp, etc), the second is numerical in double type.

Training set is made of several milions of entries and they are not linearly correlated (I checked with heatmap and correlation indexes).

**Issue**: I'd like to estimate the `Accumulator` value given the `NameItem` value through linear regression, but I think it is not what I'm actually doing.

**Question**: How can I do It?

I first divided the dataset in `training set` and `data set`:

`(trainDF, testDF) = df.randomSplit((0.80, 0.20), seed=42)`

After that I tried a pipeline approach, as most tutorials show:

1) I indexed NameItem

```
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="NameItem", outputCol="CategorizedItem", handleInvalid = "keep")
```

2) Then I encoded it

```
encoderInput = [indexer.getOutputCol()]
encoderOutput = ["EncodedItem"]
encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=encoderInput, outputCols=encoderOutput)
```

3) And also assembled it

```
assemblerInput = encoderOutput
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInput, outputCol="features")
```

After that I continued with the effective **training**:

```
lr = LinearRegression(labelCol="Accumulator")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, encoder, assembler, lr])
lrModel = pipeline.fit(trainDF)
```

That's what I obtain when I apply the prediction on the **test set**:

```
predictions = lrModel.transform(testDF).show(5, False)
```

```
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
|NameItem      |Accumulator      |CategorizedItem|EncodedItem      |features                       |prediction        |
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
|Speed         |44000.00000000   |265.0          |(688,[265],[1.0])|(689,[265,688],[1.0,44000.0])  |44000.100892495786|
|Speed         |245000.00000000  |265.0          |(688,[265],[1.0])|(689,[265,688],[1.0,245000.0]) |245000.09963708033|
|Temp          |4473860.00000000 |66.0           |(688,[66],[1.0]) |(689,[66,688],[1.0,4473860.0]) |4473859.874261986 |
|Temp          |6065.00000000    |66.0           |(688,[66],[1.0]) |(689,[66,688],[1.0,6065.0])    |6065.097757082314 |
|Temp          |10140.00000000   |66.0           |(688,[66],[1.0]) |(689,[66,688],[1.0,10140.0])   |10140.097731630483|
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

How can it be possible that for the same categorical feature (for example `Temp`) I get 3 different predictions?

Even though they are very close to the expected value, I feel there's something wrong.

Comment: Do you really have 688 categories in `NameItem`?

Comment: @desertnaut in the training set, yes

Comment: Seems like there is a bug in `VectorAssembler`; don't have time to investigate deeper now, so please try the answer below, leave feedback, and I may come back tomorrow afternoon to dig deeper (what's your Spark version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can it be possible that for the same categorical feature (for example `Temp`) I get 3 different predictions?

It's because somehow your output `Accumulator` has found its way into `features` (which of course should not be the case), so the model just "predicts" (essentially copies) this part of the input; that's why the predictions are *so* "accurate"...

Seems like the `VectorAssembler` messes things up. Thing is, you don't really need a `VectorAssembler` here, since in fact you only have a "single" feature (the one-hot encoded sparse vector in `EncodedItem`). This *might* be the reason why `VectorAssembler` behaves like that here (it is asked to "assemble" a single feature), but in any case this would be a bug.

So what I suggest is to get rid of the `VectorAssembler`, and rename the `EncodedItem` directly as `features`, i.e.:

```
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="NameItem", outputCol="CategorizedItem", handleInvalid = "keep")

encoderInput = [indexer.getOutputCol()]
encoderOutput = ["features"]  # 1st change
encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=encoderInput, outputCols=encoderOutput)

lr = LinearRegression(labelCol="Accumulator")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, encoder, lr])  # 2nd change
lrModel = pipeline.fit(trainDF)
```

**UPDATE** (after feedback in the comments)

> My Spark version Is 1.4.4

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue, simply because I have not access to Spark 1.4.4, which you are using. But I have confirmed that it works OK in the most recent version of Spark **2.4.4**, making me even more inclined to believe that there was indeed some bug back in v1.4, which however has subsequently been resolved.

Here is a reproduction in Spark 2.4.4, using some dummy data resembling yours:

```
spark.version
# '2.4.4'

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, OneHotEncoderEstimator, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

# dummy data resembling yours:

df = spark.createDataFrame([['Speed', 44000], 
                            ['Temp', 23000], 
                            ['Temp', 5000], 
                            ['Speed', 75000], 
                            ['Weight', 5300], 
                            ['Height', 34500], 
                            ['Weight', 6500]], 
                            ['NameItem', 'Accumulator'])

df.show()
# result:
+--------+-----------+
|NameItem|Accumulator|
+--------+-----------+
|   Speed|      44000|
|    Temp|      23000|
|    Temp|       5000|
|   Speed|      75000|
|  Weight|       5300|
|  Height|      34500|
|  Weight|       6500|
+--------+-----------+

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="NameItem", outputCol="CategorizedItem", handleInvalid = "keep")

encoderInput = [indexer.getOutputCol()]
encoderOutput = ["EncodedItem"]
encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=encoderInput, outputCols=encoderOutput)

assemblerInput = encoderOutput
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInput, outputCol="features")

lr = LinearRegression(labelCol="Accumulator")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, encoder, assembler, lr])
lrModel = pipeline.fit(df) 
lrModel.transform(df).show() # predicting on the same df, for simplicity
```

The result of the last `transform` is

```
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|NameItem|Accumulator|CategorizedItem|  EncodedItem|     features|        prediction|
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|   Speed|      44000|            2.0|(4,[2],[1.0])|(4,[2],[1.0])|           59500.0|
|    Temp|      23000|            1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|(4,[1],[1.0])|14000.000000000004|
|    Temp|       5000|            1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|(4,[1],[1.0])|14000.000000000004|
|   Speed|      75000|            2.0|(4,[2],[1.0])|(4,[2],[1.0])|           59500.0|
|  Weight|       5300|            0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|(4,[0],[1.0])| 5900.000000000004|
|  Height|      34500|            3.0|(4,[3],[1.0])|(4,[3],[1.0])|           34500.0|
|  Weight|       6500|            0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|(4,[0],[1.0])| 5900.000000000004|   
+--------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

from where you can see that:

1. The `features` now do **not** include the values of the output variable `Accumulator`, as it should be indeed; in fact, as I had argued above, `features` is now identical with `EncodedItem`, making the `VectorAssembler` redundant, exactly as we should expect since we only have one single feature.
2. The `prediction` values are now identical for the same values of `NameItem`, again as we would expect them to be, plus that they are less accurate and thus more realistic.

So, most certainly, your issue has to do with the *vastly outdated* Spark version 1.4.4 you are using. Spark has made leaps since v1.4, and you should seriously consider updating...

Comment: I got the same result even without the assembler. My Spark version Is 1.4.4